# Game Packet System

Tags: c#, game, .net, server

Usually I'll have around 200 packets, but for the purpose of this question I've only include 1 packet in the code, the rest is the same principle as if there was still 200.

Here is a packet system, when new messages come in the `ExecutePacket` method will be called from the Player's class, where they'll expecute the incoming packet.

Here is the packet controller, this class handles and stores all the incoming packets.

```
internal class PacketController
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, IIncomingPacketEvent> _packets;

    public void ExecutePacket(Player player, IncomingPacket packet)
    {
        if (!_packets.TryGetValue(packet.Header, out var packetEvent))
        {
            Logger.Log("Unhandled packet: " + packet.Id);
            return;
        }

        Logger.Log("Handled packet: " + packet.Id);

        packetEvent.Execute();
    }

    public void LoadPackets()
    {
        LoadHandshake();
    }

    private void LoadHandshake()
    {
        _packets.Add(IncomingPacketHeaders.GetClientKeyEvent, new GetClientKeyEvent());
    }
}
```

Incoming and Outgoing packets have headers, which in simple terms are identifiers (IDs).

```
class IncomingPacketHeaders
{
    public const int GetClientKeyEvent = 2042;
}

class OutgoingPacketHeaders
{
    public const int SendSpecialKey = 9254;
}
```

The rest of the code

```
interface IIncomingPacketEvent
{
    void Execute();
}

class GetClientKeyEvent : IIncomingPacketEvent
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // Execute the packet...
    }
}
```

Almost forgot, OutgoingPackets are "composers" (what we call them).

```
internal class SendSpecialKey : OutgoingPacket
{
    public SendSpecialKey() : base(OutgoingPacketHeaders.SendSpecialKey)
    {
        WriteString("some special key");
    }
}
```

Here are the `IncomingPacket` and `OutgoingPacket classes also.

```
public class IncomingPacket
{
    private byte[] _body;
    private int _pointer;
    public int Header;

    public IncomingPacket(int messageId, byte[] body)
    {
        Load(messageId, body);
    }

    public int RemainingLength => _body.Length - _pointer;

    public void Load(int messageId, byte[] body)
    {
        if (body == null)
        {
            body = new byte[0];
        }

        Header = messageId;
        _body = body;

        _pointer = 0;
    }

    public void AdvancePointer(int i)
    {
        _pointer += i * 4;
    }

    public byte[] ReadBytes(int bytes)
    {
        if (bytes > RemainingLength)
        {
            bytes = RemainingLength;
        }

        var data = new byte[bytes];

        for (var i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        {
            data[i] = _body[_pointer++];
        }

        return data;
    }

    public byte[] PlainReadBytes(int bytes)
    {
        if (bytes > RemainingLength)
        {
            bytes = RemainingLength;
        }

        var data = new byte[bytes];

        for (int x = 0, y = _pointer; x < bytes; x++, y++)
        {
            data[x] = _body[y];
        }

        return data;
    }

    public byte[] ReadFixedValue()
    {
        return ReadBytes(EncodingUtilities.DecodeInt16(ReadBytes(2)));
    }

    public string ReadString()
    {
        return PlusEnvironment.GetDefaultEncoding().GetString(ReadFixedValue());
    }

    public bool ReadBoolean()
    {
        return RemainingLength > 0 && _body[_pointer++] == Convert.ToChar(1);
    }

    public int ReadInt()
    {
        if (RemainingLength < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var data = PlainReadBytes(4);
        var i = EncodingUtilities.DecodeInt32(data);

        _pointer += 4;

        return i;
    }
}
```

And outgoing

```
public class OutgoingPacket
{
    private readonly List<byte> _body;

    private readonly Encoding _encoding;
    protected readonly int Id;

    public OutgoingPacket(int id)
    {
        _body = new List<byte>();
        _encoding = Encoding.Default;

        Id = id;
        WriteShort(id);
    }

    public void WriteByte(int b)
    {
        _body.Add((byte) b);
    }

    private void WriteBytes(IReadOnlyList<byte> b, bool isInt) // d
    {
        if (isInt)
        {
            for (var i = b.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                _body.Add(b[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _body.AddRange(b);
        }
    }

    public void WriteDouble(double d)
    {
        var raw = Math.Round(d, 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (raw.Length == 1)
        {
            raw += ".0";
        }

        WriteString(raw.Replace(',', '.'));
    }

    public void WriteString(string s)
    {
        WriteShort(s.Length);
        WriteBytes(_encoding.GetBytes(s), false);
    }

    public void WriteShort(int s)
    {
        WriteBytes(BitConverter.GetBytes((short) s), true);
    }

    public void WriteInteger(int i)
    {
        WriteBytes(BitConverter.GetBytes(i), true);
    }

    public void WriteBoolean(bool b)
    {
        WriteBytes(new[] {(byte) (b ? 1 : 0)}, false);
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        var final = new List<byte>();

        final.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(_body.Count));
        final.Reverse();
        final.AddRange(_body);

        return final.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I won’t share the client side code, as that's totally unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of small things to say, I've certainly missed something, but here goes!

### Endianness

It is apparent that you have thought about endianness from the `isInt` parameter which is good, and while this will certainly work fine on most machines, you shouldn't be assuming the endianness of the system: check [`IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to determine that, and only reverse the bytes of supplied by `BitConverter.GetBytes(*)` if it is not the correct endianness (I assume you are using Big ('Network') Endian).

### Readonly Fields

You have suitably marked the fields in `OutgoingPacket` as `readonly`: the same treatment should be given to those in `IncomingPacket`, *esspecially* `Header` which is currently publically settable.

### Incoming/Outgoing Encoding Mismatch

Consider `IncomingPacket.ReadString()`: I do not like that this jumps into some other part of the code to read strings which were written out by a simple short-prefixed string in an encoding that is accessed by a different mechanism. This looks like a maintainability nightmare, because changes to the `PlusEnvironment.GetDefaultEncoding()` could easily be made without updating `OutgoingPacket`. These coupled methods should be defined together, so that it is obvious they are coupled.

The same issue applies almost everywhere. My suggestion would be to extend `EncodingUtilities` to provide `GetBytes` style methods so that all of the concerns with endianness and encoding are handled in one place, and tear out all of the 'custom' stuff in `OutgoingPacket`

### Making up data

In `IncomingPacket.ReadInt()` you have

```cs
if (RemainingLength < 1)
{
    return 0;
}
```

What is this doing?! There is nothing in `OutgoingPacket` that enables you to crop an `int` if it happens to be zero and the last value: what utility can this check possibly provide?

If you are trying to read an `int`, and there is no `int` to read, you should probably be throwing an exception. Missing data isn't something the system should be dealing with by making it up: the programmer has made an error and *they want to know about it*, so tell them in the most helpful way possible by throwing an exception.

The same comments can be made for `IncomingPacket.(Plain)ReadBytes(int bytes)`.

```cs
if (bytes > RemainingLength)
{
    bytes = RemainingLength;
}
```

I asked for `bytes` bytes, don't give me fewer than `bytes` bytes! (Incidentally, I don't like the variable name `bytes`, it sounds like a buffer: `count` or `byteCount` would seem clearer). Again: throw an exception: *tell* me there were not enough bytes when you first realise.

### `PacketController.ExecutePacket(Player, IncomingPacket)`

This code never passes the packet to the packet event: you have all this code to read/write the payload for the packet, but you don't seem to be doing anything with it.

```cs
// Execute the packet...
```

Which packet?!

### `IncomingPacket.ReadBoolean()`

... I feel I must be missing something: why are you comparing a `byte` to a `char`?

```cs
return RemainingLength > 0 && _body[_pointer++] == Convert.ToChar(1);
```

Why not just compare the byte to the `byte` value `1`?

Again, `RemainingLength > 0` is helping no-one.

I'd be inclined to pull out a method that reads a single byte (e.g. `ReadByte()`), because currently this one line of code (I'd expand the `if` as well) does a number of jobs.

```cs
/// <Summary> Reads a single byte from the stream </Summary>
public byte ReadByte()
{
    if (RemainingLength < 1)
        throw new IncomingPacketException("Attempted to read a Byte from a consumed packet");

    return _body[_pointer++];
}

/// <Summary> Reads a boolean value from the stream </Summary>    
public bool ReadBoolean()
{
    return ReadByte() == (byte)1;
}
```

You have a public `OutgoingPacket.WriteByte(byte)` method, so it seems silly not to have a public `IncomingPacket.ReadByte()` method also.

### `IncomingPacket.ReadInt()`

This is the only method that uses the `PlainReadBytes(int)` method. Why does it not just use `ReadBytes(int)`? Why is `PlainReadBytes(int)` even provided?

You are loading tasks onto `ReadInt()` (`_pointer += 4`) that should be done by `ReadBytes(int)`, which is inconsistent with most other methods in `OutgoingPacket`.

### `OutgoingPacket.WriteByte(int b)`

Why is this taking an `int`?! `WriteByte(??)` should take a `_byte_`! If, as a consumer of this method, I want to write an `int` and pretend that it is a `byte`, then I should have to perform that cast myself. All you've done here is written in an unclear API which will help to introduce copy-and-paste errors. In the very least, this behaviour of casting should be documented.

### `OutgoingPacket.WriteBytes(IReadOnlyList<byte>, bool)`

I'd be inclined to break this into two methods, one for things where endianness matters, and one for things where endianness doesn't matter. This makes it much clearer at the call-site that the correct method is being used, rather than anyone looking at the code having to understand the second parameter and remember which way round it is.

### `OutgoingPacket.WriteDouble(double)`

You are already using `CultureInvarient`, there is no need to replace commas with points.

Is there a good reason you are manually appending a ".0" to a double which encodes to a single digit?

All this double stuff is a bit scary, because it looks like a general purpose writer, but in reality it is cropping your `double`, and this is completely undocumented. If your entire system is built around the concept of not having more than one decimal of precision, then that's OK (it probably still warrants a comment) but if not, then this looks like a great way to confuse someone unfamiliar with the code.

All that said, there is no `IncomingPacket.ReadDouble()` method, so this method is kind of useless.

### `Outgoing.WriteBool(bool b)`

I'd have this lean on `WriteByte(byte)`, it's just cleaner.

```cs
WriteByte((byte)(b ? 1 : 0));
```

### `OutgoingBytes.GetBytes()`

I don't like that this uses a different set of code for writing an endian-flipped integer... but you'd need a heavy refactoring to change this.